# JQuery submit form parameters are empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, post, content-type

I am submiting form using `$('#myForm').submit` my rest service accepts content-type of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, but when using submit() I can't see the request in XHR tab in browser developer tools and the form parameters doesn't reach the Rest service, I could use AJAX post and specify content-type, but Rest service produces octet stream in other words the response contains a downloadable file csv/pdf, what could be the solution to submit form correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Why you are not using $.ajax() with type:"post" ?. you can set header easily  there

```
// Request with custom header
$.ajax({
    url: 'foo/bar',
    type: 'post',
    headers: { 'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
    data: {}, // object of your data
    success: function(response){
       alert(response)
    }
});
```

IF your api response is in octet stream or downloadable file then you have to create virtual form and post it through jQuery, Because through AJAX it is not possible to download file.. When file is download content of current page will remain same event form is posted.

```
function autoGenerateAndSubmitForm(method, url, post_data) {
    var element = document.getElementById("virtual_form");
    if(element != null )
    {
        element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
    }
    var form = document.createElement("form");
    form.setAttribute("id", "virtual_form");
    form.setAttribute("style", "display:none;");
    //form.setAttribute("target", "_blank"); // remove comment if you want to open it in new tab
    form.method = method;
    form.action = url;   
    for(i in post_data)
    {
         var element=document.createElement("input");
         element.value=post_data[i];
         element.name=i;
         form.appendChild(element); 
    }
    document.body.appendChild(form);
    form.submit();
    form.parentNode.removeChild(form);
}
```

Call below function with your poper arguments

```
autoGenerateAndSubmitForm('POST','your_url',{your_post_data_object:"Here"});
```

Comment: Yes with ajax post the parameters reach the rest service, but my rest service returns octet stream so the ajax error is thrown because it can't handle this kind of type

Comment: can you post response from API, or in reponse it is downloaded file?

Comment: Yes it is downloaded file, to be more exact it's csv/pdf.

Comment: ohh... so please modify your question accordingly  I have solution for this :)... meanwhile I am modify my answer

Comment: I have updated my answer, thanks... let me know its works for you or not

Comment: I tried it but still parameters came as nulls and request type is document.

Comment: can you post your code in question and which API you are using?

Answer (score 0):

After reading your modified Question usually if the parameters are empty at the API it could be caused by the following.

1. Form is Not Properly Serialized
2. The Content Type Specified Is Not what your API is Accepting
3. When you are using ajax make sure your form does not specify any action and methods else there might be a problem.
4. The model the API is expecting doesn't match what the form has submitted
5. When using Ajax change your button type to "button" instead of "submit".